# Secure web api when someone using get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in asp net framework. I want to secure my aspnet framework so to not allow anyone which has not the certificate key to access in my application.
I read that the best way to do this is to use token.

```
[Authorize]
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
   return new string[] { "value1", "value2"};
}
```

I found this but it works only when i use post.

```
 public string Get(HttpRequestMessage  request)
    {

        var token = ActionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        return token;
    }
```

When i use get it doesnt return anything

Using this i'm getting error Authorization has been denied for this request.

So how can i change my token key or how can set client to send it when it makes a request?
In client i'm using httpcilent method for get or post items.

Comment: How are you handling authorization (i.e. checking the token)?

Comment: Can i check authorization inside get routine? Do i need to ask for username and password in every http request?